# How to send a ajax request for particular div

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2

```
<select onchange="filter('<?php echo $url;?>')">
    <option value="none" $none>--- Sort By ---</option>
    <option value="date" $date>Newest</option>
    <option value="price" $price>Price</option>
    <option value="name" $name>Name</option>
</select>


<div class="my-products">
    //Structure of my custom products
</div>
```

I wrote a Script like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var Jquery=jQuery.noConflict();
      function filter(url1) {
          var data1 = "&id=10";
          try {
              Jquery.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    type : 'post',
                    data: data1,
                    success: function(response){
                        if (response) {
                           var string = Jquery('.my-products', response);
                           Jquery('.my-products').html(string);
                        }
                    }
              });
          }
          catch(e){ }
          return false;
    }
</script>
```

Because of this its working fine... But my problem is in background it is updating complete page because of this i'm loosing some sensitive data.

But my plan is to update only particular `div` not the complete page.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Is your div class is `.my-products` or that class applies to all pge?

Comment: Try putting `return false`

Comment: @ShijuKBabu No... That is my div class name

Comment: To update particular div,  you can give id attribute to that paticular div `<div id="myproducts"></div>` and change this line `Jquery('#myproducts').html(string);`

Comment: It should work. Just add `return false` in the end of function (after catch).

Comment: @ShijuKBabu there only i added that code & please take a look about my updated code

Comment: I'd try and see if `$('.my-products').load(url1, data, null);` works

Comment: Naresh can u please tell me.what are the content  you have sending??

Comment: @AmitBera I'm sending only Id based on that id same file is updating thats y i gave same url in url1. in this file i have so many conditions if() {--- if(){---}else{--- }else{----}------ } like this Based on id val it is updating

Answer (score 0):

All that is needed to make this work is a return false; or e.preventDefault()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var Jquery=jQuery.noConflict();
      function filter(url1) {
          var data1 = "&id=10";
          try {
              Jquery.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    type : 'post',
                    data: data1,
                    success: function(response){
                        if (response) {
                           var string = Jquery('.my-products', response);
                           Jquery('.my-products').html(string);
                        }
                    }
              });
          }
          catch(e){ }
          e.preventDefault(); 
          return false; // any one of this two should work
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code how you have called the function filter. I mean on which event from html

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `return flase`

```
function filter(url1) {
          var data1 = "&id=10";
          try {
              Jquery.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    type : 'post',
                    data: data1,
                    success: function(response){
                        if (response) {
                           var htmldata = Jquery('<div/>').html(response);
                           Jquery('.my-products').html(htmldata);
                        }
                    }
              });
          }
          catch(e){ }
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply  But this one also not working

Comment: Is your response is some html data?

Comment: for this div i have the code in same HTML.. and also i have some other blocks i'm combining these with Xml code

Comment: Please provide some more data. Your HTML page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45096/discussion-between-naresh-and-shiju-k-babu)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a response?

Comment: Is it replaces the div content with response and then whole page reloads?

Comment: Its updating the whole page but var string = Jquery('.col-main', response);Jquery('.col-main').html(string); these two lines code is for to show that .col-main div in frontend .. &  my plan is i don't want to update entire page i want update only that div...